# Exporting imported macros

Tags: symfony, drupal, twig

I want to be able to import macros from one central file, but have each macro in a separate file.

My current approach is having a `macros.twig`, which imports all the other macros.

```
{% from 'foo-macro.twig' import foo %}
{% from 'bar-macro.twig' import bar %}
{% from 'baz-macro.twig' import baz %}
```

But when importing it in `example.twig`:

```
{% from 'macros.twig' import foo, bar, baz %}

{{ foo('foo arg') }}
{{ bar('bar arg') }}
{{ baz('baz arg') }}
```

`Error: Macro "foo" is not defined in template "macros.twig".`

I also tried including each macro in `macros.twig` via `include`. Same issue.

I there a way I could not find in the docs?

[Here's a TwigFiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/mitiap)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the macro in each file you want to use it.
This has been changed in `Twig 2.0` and has been documented

> **Macros**
>
> As of Twig 2.0, macros imported in a file are not available in child templates anymore (via an include call for instance). You need to import macros explicitly in each file where you are using them.

[source](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/deprecated.html#macros)